# How can I disable deletion of inline objects when using django-reverse-admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

This is my `ModelAdmin`:

```
class ComputerAdmin(ReverseModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('employee', 'ip', 'mac', 'name', 'hardware')
    list_filter = ('employee__branch', )
    inline_type = 'tabular'
    inline_reverse = ['hardware', ]
    show_full_result_count = False
```

This is how it shows when adding a new computer:

[image]

As you can see, I don't want to have the delete column and delete icon, because I have a foreign key so only one element is allowed. How can I do that?

Does `django-reverse-admin` have anything like `has_delete_permisison` for inlines only and not the whole `ModelAdmin`? I have already searched in documentation with no results, which is why I am posting here.

I updated my code as below:

```
class HardwareInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Hardware

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('group', 'branch', 'name')
    list_filter = ('group', )

class ComputerAdmin(ReverseModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('employee', 'ip', 'mac', 'name', 'hardware')
    list_filter = ('employee__group', 'employee__branch', )
    inline_type = 'tabular'
    inline_reverse = [ { 'field_name': 'hardware', 'admin_class': HardwareInline } ]
```

The delete column disappeared from inline, but I get a delete button under it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can find the answer from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin/issues/154#issuecomment-729739280):

You need to explicitly create an inline, and add a `has_delete_permission` method to it:

```
class HardwareInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Hardware

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

And then in your `ReverseModelAdmin`, you need to specify the `'admin_class'`:

```
class ComputerAdmin(ReverseModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('employee', 'ip', 'mac', 'name', 'hardware')
    list_filter = ('employee__group', 'employee__branch')
    inline_type = 'tabular'
    inline_reverse = [
        {'field_name': 'hardware', 'admin_class': HardwareInline},
    ]
```

This should hide the "Delete" checkbox.

Comment: Does it work with tabular inline too ?

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Try it?

Comment: the delete column disappeared but now i have delete button under. You can see my updated code

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Hmm, what happens if you click that button?

Comment: tried it but didn't work

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Idk then, to me this seems like it should work just fine.